# Totally ditching chest training

Tags: muscle, strength, strength-training, training, muscle-imbalance

What are the implications and negative side effects of NOT training the chest muscles?

I train my entire body from the jaw and neck down to the feet but I'm thinking on making the pectoral muscles the only exception.

My reasoning:
I personally see no point  in training the chest mostly for two reasons. 1 the chest adds little to no thickness or width to your body, one can perfectly have a big frame with bony chest . 2 The chest can only be seen  when naked so only your girlfriend will ever know if you have a small or big chest, just like abs but training your core has a point as it makes all lifts easier while chest training can even worsen your posture.

My actual routine, i switch variations periodically...some times i completelly change exercises but the muscles worked remain the same.

It may look long but i superset everything, I only stay 1 hour max in the gym.
Monday : 10x10  calf extensions, 2x50 calf flexion, 10x10 squats or lunges,3x15 side bents,3x15 russian twists,3x15 side crunches,3x15 side knee raises,10x10 Bent over rows,5x20 power shrugs,5x20 cable tricep overhead extension,2x50  neck flexion.

Thursday: 3x5 calf extensions,3x5 weighted inverted rows,3x2 weighted pistol squats,5x5 Rack pulls,5x5 overhead tricep extension,3x10 handstand push ups,3x50 neck flexion.

Saturday: 10x10 pull ups,10x10 W raises or face pulls,5x10 behind the back deadlifts,10x10 woodchoppers,2x100 cable tricep kickback,2x50 neck flexion.

And at home i use bands to train my biting force, and also do some finger flexions and extensions.

no chest,so is it obligatory to train chest or i can ignore it with no worries? What can go wrong if i don't train my chest?

Comment: Im concerned if i will get some physiological problems from not training it or if its dangerous.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by not training the chest (i.e. not doing any bench work, incline or flat, no press ups, etc)? Are you still training shoulders and back (overhead press, pull up, etc)? What's the rest of your routine? As far as I remember reading, old time lifters never had benches, so didn't do any direct chest work, they did do a lot more overhead work than most people do now-a-days though

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: I wonder, wouldn't not training the pectorals directly would impact the pushing performance?

Comment: the only pushing exercises I do are handstands and sometimes i use my pecs to push during free climbing but I don't find it has a big impact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will always want to keep a balance between antagonist musclegroups. This means a strong latissimus with weak pectoralis will lead to imbalances which might negatively affect your movement and posture.

Also your argument about pectoralis not being visible with clothes on is wrong. Wearing somewhat tight clothes will reveal the size very well.

While you might put a different focus, not training a muscle group at all is pretty much never a good idea.